# Replace text tokens with ExtJS components

Tags: javascript, extjs

In `ExtJS 4.X` I implemented one parser which enabled dynamically changing some arbitrary tokens with `ExtJS` components. The raw text could look like:

```
Some text {"xtype":"textfield", "name": "attr_1_"} and some number {"xtype": "numberfield", "name": "attr_2_"}
```

And the resulting would look like:

```
Some text [ExtJS textfield component] and some number [ExtJS numberfield component]
```

However, in modern `ExtJS` it all looks like:

[image]

Internally, my parser changes `{"xtype":"textfield", "name": "attr_1_"}` to hidden `spans`, assigns them an id and renders a component to this `span`. It worked in previous versions of `ExtJS`, but no longer works in `ExtJS 6.X`, obviously, because of some styling. But I'm not sure how to fix it and what style to override.

Comment: In other words, I do not want to render each component at new blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Pheew! I found an answer. I should have rendered `ExtJS` components to `divs` with such a css style:

```
display:inline-block
```

In previuos versions, I could just render to `spans`, but now it does not work for some reason.